# Заменить пробелы на запятые?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Как в JavaScript заменить пробелы на запятые в переменной?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var str = "Привет как дела?";
alert(str.replace(/ /g, ','));
```

Обновил ответ, т.к. он выбран как правильный, но в нем присутствовал изъян описанный в комментариях

Comment: Так данный квантификатор \s заменит не только пробелы но и \n-новую строку, \t-табуляцию т.д. \n

Answer (score 9):

```
var str = "Привет как дела?\n\t\t\tfin.";
alert(str.replace(/ /ig, ','));
```

Comment: Nuklon, Спасибо! Благодаря Вам отловил проблему так, как от Вас узнал, что квантификатор \s это не только пробел но и перенос каретки, и табуляция.

Comment: @Илья наверняка ещё и всякие `nbsp` и прочие пробельные символы, в Юникоде их много.

Comment: @NickVolynkin `nbsp` точно нет, а вот символов из Юникода достаточно. Описание тут можно найти https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @likerRr там в большой регулярке есть `u00A0`, это как раз неразрывный пробел. https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/

Comment: @NickVolynkin с формулировкой `неразрывный пробел` и `u00A0` согласен, а вот `nbsp` может ввести в заблуждение, как символ неразрывного пробела в html